# SQL - selecting rows with date and time conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select all of the rows where it is less than or equal to today's date (This part is working) but i dont want the rows for today where the $time is less than the endt time.

test table: {ID, date, status, checkid}

check table: {checkid, startt, endt}: start and end are time values like below.

```
$time = '15:00:00'; 

$query = ("SELECT test.ID, test.status, check.startt, check.endt FROM test INNER JOIN check ON test.checkid=check.checkid 
WHERE test.date <='$date' AND $time < check.endt");
```

The query wont display anything if the time is less than the end time in the check table. I know am doing something wrong but i cant figure it out, i am trying an if statement atm.

Comment: you must invert the second condition $time > check.endt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically code what you described... I.e. Special handling when `test.date` = "today"

Condition "1" on date only always applies (but excludes today)
Condition "2" involves both date and time (for today).

```
WHERE    test.date < $date
      OR (test.date = $date AND check.endt <= $time)
```

NB: Note that if you try *combine the date and time so you can perform a single comparison*: this is possible; but the query would be unable to leverage indexes, so is not advisable.

---

PS: There is a more direct translation of your requirement. Unfortunately it's a little more verbose and the optimiser might fail to find the optimal plan.

```
where   test.date <= $date
    and test.id not in (
        select  test.id
        from    ...
        where   test.date = $date
            and check.endt > $time
        )
```

Also for platforms that support the `EXCEPT` clause (apparently many popular ones EXCEPT mysql):

```
select  Col1, Col2
from    ...
where   test.date <= $date
except
select  Col1, Col2
from    ...
where   test.date = $date and check.endt > $time
```

The `EXCEPT` syntax reads very naturally even though it's quite verbose.

Comment: Thank you it worked, spent so much time on a if else statement.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments, do the other methods just provide efficiency in completing the query? Also would the condition you have given work in ordering?

Comment: @S.S They're just alternative approaches to the problem. It's not always easy to translate complex conditions into a simple where clause. So it's useful to know how to use a `NOT IN ({subquery})`. As I said EXCEPT is very readable (for platforms that support it). If performance is a concern then: ***(1) test (2) measure (3) change (4) compare (5) rinse-repeat***. As for ordering: In SQL whenever you want specific ordering you ***must use*** an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. ***Never assume*** ordering without it (even if data "looks" sorted).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes i am using the order by to try and get results by date and time like two rows with the same date but different times ordered (databases will have many dates and times). I am confused with the sql statement does the OR statement get executed last as the results i get are randomly ordered without any order by.

Comment: @S.S SQL is a _declarative_ languages. You specify the "rules" and you shouldn't think about the sequence of steps the server will apply to produce the result set. It's free to process in any order that the optimiser calculates will yield the best performance. ***In SQL you should think in SETS, not in steps.***